# 2D Lists in python

Tags: python

I have a 2d list and a class to get users input for row and column and retrieve that object but if that row/column doesn't exist it says that list out of index but i want it return saying error

this is my current code

```
return self.object[row][column]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try:
    return self.object[row][column]
except IndexError:
    return "error"
```

Comment: @user998316 - on which line? Can you post the surrounding code?

Comment: error is on line except IndexError:, has this sign under except^ and the error is SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: What's the line before that, then? Can you paste the actual block of code as you have it in your file?